# SQL Replace, but to replace unique values

Tags: sql, replace

I'm trying to use REPLACE within the very basic SQL editor on one of our systems, as below:

```
replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(CFCFIncidentRootCause,

'0', 'No Root Cause'),

'2', 'Hardware Fault'),

'1', 'Data Issue'),

'4', 'Change Failure'),

'6', 'Third Party Issue'),

'7', 'User Error Training'),

'8', 'Network Issue'),

'3', 'Software Issue'),

'5', 'Permissions'),

'11', 'Non IT Issue'),

'12', 'Unknown Root Cause'),

'13', 'Request Fulfilled'),

'14', 'Request Denied'),

'10', 'Performance Issue'),

'15', 'Security Issue')

As CFCFIncidentRootCause
```

The problem is it's not searching for the unique values, so when it displays the results I have a mix match of different results:

[image: Results]

The raw results look like this:

[Raw data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wCDX.png)

So as you can probably see i'm trying to assign a Name to each one of these unique numbers, as they each represent a different Root cause.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: If you only want distinct values then add a DISTINCT or GROUP BY to your sql. Maybe I'm not understanding.Perhaps share sample data and desired results so we can understand better.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi there, not sure how to use those functions with REPLACE.  The raw data is as you see it above, so the CFCIndcientRootCause field has a selection of values, as per the list in the formula.  But as you can see joining some of them up as it's not picking out the individual values.  There's only one value for each record in this field, ranging from 0-15.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could try using a `CASE WHEN` expression.

```
SELECT 
CASE 
WHEN CFCFIncidentRootCause = 0 THEN 'No Root Cause'
WHEN CFCFIncidentRootCause = 1 THEN 'Data Issue'
WHEN CFCFIncidentRootCause = 2 THEN 'Hardware Fault'
WHEN CFCFIncidentRootCause = 3 THEN 'Software Issue'
WHEN CFCFIncidentRootCause = 4 THEN 'Change Failure'
WHEN CFCFIncidentRootCause = 5 THEN 'Permissions'
WHEN CFCFIncidentRootCause = 6 THEN 'Third Party Issue'
WHEN CFCFIncidentRootCause = 7 THEN 'User Error Training'
WHEN CFCFIncidentRootCause = 8 THEN 'Network Issue'
WHEN CFCFIncidentRootCause = 10 THEN 'Performance Issue'
WHEN CFCFIncidentRootCause = 11 THEN 'Non IT Issue'
WHEN CFCFIncidentRootCause = 12 THEN 'Unknown Root Cause'
WHEN CFCFIncidentRootCause = 13 THEN 'Request Fulfilled'
WHEN CFCFIncidentRootCause = 14 THEN 'Request Denied'
WHEN CFCFIncidentRootCause = 15 THEN 'Security Issue'
END as CFCFIncidentRootCause
FROM table_name
```

Be aware that you do not have a code "9" in your code.

If your CFCFIncidentRootCause column is text type and not numeric you just need to put the numbers between quotation marks.

Hope this is what your were looking for (or at least points you to the right direction)

Comment: That's awesome, thanks so much!  Worked an absolute treat.  You're a star!